# Sorcery gem - logged_in? always returns false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sorcery

I'm trying to make a very simple web app using Rails and I'm using the Sorcery gem to authenticate users. I followed the tutorial [here](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/wiki/Simple-Password-Authentication) on their GitHub page, and I'm getting no where with it.

I have 2 issues which I believe are probably linked. 
The first being, when I use this before_filter `skip_before_filter :require_login, only: [:index, :new, :create]`, users can still access the page without logging in.

The other issue is, when a user tries to log in, they aren't redirected, and when I use the built in helper `logged_in?`, it always returns false. Even though there was no error message when logging in.

I've added the appropriate controllers, let me know if you need to look at anything else.

Thanks.

**user_sessions_controller.rb**

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :require_login, :except => [:destroy]

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    if @user = login(params[:email], params[:password])
      redirect_back_or_to(:users, :notice => 'Login successfull.')
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = 'Login failed'
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    logout
    redirect_to(:users, :notice => 'Logged out!')
  end
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :require_login, only: [:index, :new, :create]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to :users, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    #def user_params
    #  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :crypted_password, :salt)
    #end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  # protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :require_login


  private
    def not_authenticated
      redirect_to(login_path, :alert => "Please login first")
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has access to Users pages due to this line `skip_before_filter :require_login, only: [:index, :new, :create]`. This literally means "don't check authorization". Just remove this line.

Generally you should skip `require_login` filter only on public pages and login pages (i.e. `UserSessionsController#create` etc).

And the second issue: do you have `authenticates_with_sorcery!` in your User model?